Error when changing containerd root directory to nfsshare mount point
After changing containerd root directory to nfsshare mount point I am getting this error:
unpacking registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.28.11 (sha256:88e796a62acb5c4aa7ef40fcbdcf7b0f13e3ddc2b5322adcd07ce2e28e92fe75)...INFO[0062] apply failure, attempting cleanup             error="failed to extract layer sha256:01101290decd4480824285366ecbf9c414e437e9eacf69b790175ee160e843b4: failed to convert whiteout file \"usr/local/.wh..wh..opq\": operation not supported: unknown" key="extract-515012200-dUSs sha256:c45d3f2f87eeca5a303a560d3ed9c67ea8e46c99b1396501268d5ce635e36599"
ctr: failed to extract layer sha256:01101290decd4480824285366ecbf9c414e437e9eacf69b790175ee160e843b4: failed to convert whiteout file "usr/local/.wh..wh..opq": operation not supported: unknown

I have simply changed containerd root path from /var/lib/containerd to nfsshare (/var/nfsshare/containerd) and now it is giving me the above error and is not able to pull/unpack the images.

Container file systems use overlays to build root filesystem and OverlayFS will only work with supported base file systems and nfsshare not one of them.
